# Extract many substrings and put them into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a like this one:

`"1x 20GP 1x 40GP 1x 40HQ 5x 45HQ 2x 20RF 5x 40RQ"`

Now I want to cut the part 20GP, 40GP, 40HQ, 45HQ, 20RF, 40RQ and put them into an array. However, the thing is my string can change depends on the value that is input by the user.

Generally, I want to extract the 20GP, 40GP, 40HQ, 45HQ, 20RF, and 40RQ into an array if they appear in the string.

I am wondering what is the best way to do it. I am just learning JavaScript, one solution that comes up into my mind at the first place  is using regular expression, but I don't know where to start. Could anybody enlighten me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, this can be accomplished using RegEx fairly easy:

```
var txt = "1x 20GP 1x 40GP 1x 40HQ 5x 45HQ 2x 20RF 5x 40RQ"

var matches = txt.match(/\d+[A-Z]{2}/g); // delivers ["20GP", "40GP", "40HQ", "45HQ", "20RF", "40RQ"]
```

The expression basically means:

1. `\d+` at least one digit
2. `[A-Z]{2}` followed by exactly 2 uppercase Letters

When working with Regular Expressions, I generally use a tool like https://regex101.com/ when im stuck somewhere. This might be a good place to start learning/experimenting.

I would also recommend the Talk **/Reg(exp){2}lained/: Demystifying Regular Expressions** of Lea Verou on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkluES9Rvak)

Comment: Thanks very much. It works fantastically for me. Moreover, thanks for the pointing me to the great resource to learn regular expression. How long does it take you to master regular expression, I am just wondering? :)

Comment: Well, since I don't master it really - I have no clue. But playing aroud with those tools and some reading you can get quite far in no time. And then there is still SO in case you get stuck ;)

Answer (score 1):

For your basic input, the regex proposed by nozzleman will work.
However, if you want something more robust, you could try the following regex :

```
txt.match(/\dx\s(.*?(?=\s|$))/g);
```

[(test it here against your input)](https://regex101.com/r/O123jQ/1)

This will extract the data from a string formated as such :

```
[Number]x [data1] [Number]x [data2] ....
```

The advantage of this solution is that we do not impose any format restriction on the data. It can be longer than 3 characters, and data can be separated by tabs or newlines instead of simply spaces

Explaination of the regex :

- `\dx` : matches any number followed by the letter `x`
- `\s` : matches any blank character (space, tabs, ...)
- `(.*?(?=\s|$))` : creates a capture group containing the matched text

  - `.*?` : `?` makes our pattern [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). `.*` captures any string of characters
  - `(?=\s|$)` : `(?=` is the [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It allows us to assume a pattern will be present without capturing it. Here, we look for the pattern `\s|$`, which means any blank character or the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try your way when I have time. Have a nice day. So many amazing people here. :)